# Is a topology determined by its convergent class?

Tags: general-topology

I have seen that a topology is determined by its convergent nets from following question.
[1]: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36379/is-a-topology-determined-by-its-convergent-sequences

Moreover, the answer added the topology can be determined by convergent sequence when it is a metric space. I feel this condition strong: does it hold for first-countable space?

Comment: In a first-countable space, a set is closed if and only if it is sequentially closed. Then the answer is affirmative.

Comment: This is true and stated in the Wikipedia article on first-countable spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space#Properties

Comment: The spaces whose topologies are completely determined by their convergent sequences are the [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, even for a wider class of spaces called [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space), which are spaces in which a set is closed iff it is sequentially closed (a set $A$ is sequentially closed in $X$ iff for every sequence from $A$ that has a limit $x$ in $X$ we have $x \in A$). So if we know which sequences converge in $X$ to what limits, we know what the closed sets are, and thus what the open sets are etc., so the topology is known from its sequential convergence.

All first countable spaces are sequential. In fact a space is sequential iff it is the quotient of a first countable space, as you can read on the linked Wikipedia page.